# Can't connect two players automatched Google play Games services again after finish game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

i am working with google **realtime Multiplayer** bike racing game.when i starting a game first time two players connected(automatched).after completing the race and go to Main Menu(**Don't Quitting[shutdown] Game**),when i play again the players doesn't connect to each other.but when i **Quit** the game and **close whole App** and **restart**, the two players connect again when Play... please help whats the problem .i wrote a code on leaving the room on Exit Button.

```
public void Exit()
{
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();

Application.LoadLevel("Main_Menu_Scene");
}
```

don't understand Whats the problem. is play play services not stoping? how to solve it please help.

Comment: Can you share the logs? if there are any issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not auto-matched opponents?

Comment: Nope i haven't check this.. but i need automatched opponent only.. i think this is not due to automatched opponent.  i think player may not be disconnected from Room when i exit to main menu.